# String sum function in python

Tags: python, dataframe

```
product_group=all_data.groupby('Product')

product_group.sum()
```

While executing I am getting error as:

```
datetime64 type does not support sum operations
```

Comment: Please provide more information about your code.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by "summing" a list of datetimes?

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the elements of the product_group into something that can be summed, like integers, then cast the integers back into a datetime64

Comment: product_group=all_data.groupby('Product')
product_group=pd.to_numeric(all_data['Product'])
product_group.sum()


getting again error

ValueError: Unable to parse string "USB-C Charging Cable" at position 0